# Uploading bundle to Closed Track on Google Play says I've signed it with wrong key

Tags: android, react-native, encryption, google-play, google-play-console

I uploaded a release bundle `app-release.aab` to a Closed Testing track on Google Play. I'm trying to upload a new bundle to the same track, but it gives me this error:

```
Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your App Bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:
SHA1: 00:57:3F:AD:13:3E:8A:F6:E4:45:19:20:77:F7:6F:82:9F:65:F7:A3
but the certificate used to sign the App Bundle you uploaded has fingerprint:
SHA1: 5E:8F:16:06:2E:A3:CD:2C:4A:0D:54:78:76:BA:A6:F3:8C:AB:F6:25
```

I get the same error if I create a new track on the same project and try to upload it. I tried the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507156/your-android-app-bundle-is-signed-with-the-wrong-key-ensure-that-your-app-bundl) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67968372/error-your-android-app-bundle-is-signed-with-the-wrong-key-how-to-sign-apk-a) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62310707/your-android-app-bundle-is-signed-with-the-wrong-key-while-updating-my-app-in-fl), but all of them focus on following the correct procedure for generating the bundle file. None of the solutions has made a difference in my scenario. I'm following [this guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android) on creating the bundle. I'm wondering if I created one key the first time I uploaded the bundle, and every time after that have been using a different one, but should be using the first one.

Does anyone have any insight on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you exported your private upload key when you released your app for the first time, then you have to use the same key for later releases. Go to Release->Setup->App integrity section of your app. On the bottom you will find your private upload key and you have to use that key to sign your app for later releases. If you have lost or compromised your upload key by any chance then go to this link https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en and
check out the "Lost or compromised upload key?" section of that page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know if I've lost or compromised the original key because I don't know where I'd look to find it. Do you know how?